# System.DmlException: Update failed.: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER problem

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I have object called `Test` with fields: `name` and `checkbox`.

When I add first record, I set the checkbox of this record to true. Next, I add second record.

[image: Test__c Tab "All" List View]

If the checkbox in the second record will be changed to true I want to change the first record checkbox to false so I write a apex trigger to do that:

```
trigger checkUpdate on Test__c (before update) {
        List<Test__c> listTest = [SELECT id, name, checkbox__c FROM Test__c where checkbox__c = true ];
        for(integer i = 0 ; i < listTest.size(); i++){
            listTest[i].checkbox__c = false;
        }
        update listTest;
}
```

but after edit the second record trigger was fired and I get that exception:

[image: Error Message]

It caused by fact that DML call on records that are in the trigger. But how do I properly implement this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement this functionality declaratively, via `Workflow Rule`. A solid axiom of Salesforce development could be framed:

> Whenever you have a choice between declarative and programmatic functionality, choose the declarative option.

Typical exceptions to this rule would be:

- Performance - functionality needs to be optimized
- Error Handling - declarative functionality does not provide optimal user experience

I'm sure there are others as well, the key is to make sure you only choose the programmatic option (here `Apex Trigger`) if you have a compelling reason to do so. Try to write as little code as possible.

---

If you are trying to make it so only one record can have this box checked at a time, you may indeed need `Apex`. However, note the documentation on [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) states:

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

So you need to move your logic to an `after` trigger. It seems like you should also trigger `after insert`, but your question doesn't make your requirements very clear.

Comment: Thanks for tip.  Second question - there is a possibility that Workflow Rule   will for the first record in the case when the object is empty set the checkbox to true?

Comment: I'm having a hard time with your grammar. I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry. I asked for Workflow Rule. If the Workflow Rule handle me case that
the object is empty and I want to always set to first record checkbox to true. Only when I add the first record to the object.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think he is saying that he wants to know if Workflow Rules can handle the condition where if the OBJECT has no records, he wants the first record inserted into that object to mark his Boolean to True

Comment: @Adamo if your design requirement is that only ONE record in this object can have Checkbox = True at any time, then Workflow Rules will not do the job for you.

Comment: @Morgan Right, if that is the requirement it must be trigger, it just needs to use `after` events. I added that interpretation to my answer.

Comment: Exactly @MorganMarchese

Comment: My case: Object - no records. Add first record - after add, change checbox to true. Add second record with checkbox = false, when second record was edited and set checkbox = true the checkbox from first record automaticly change to false

Comment: Something like radio buttons. Only one checkbox checked.

Comment: @Adamo Moving the logic to an `after` trigger event should fix your errors. You should make that change and try to get the actual implementation working by yourself.